# asp.Net 2005 "Could not load type"

Tags: deployment, load, asp.net

Although I have seen dozens of forum questions relating to "Could not load type", none of the advice in them seemed to apply to my situation.

I wrote a new web application using aspx.net VB 2005. It is tiny, with just 2 pages, 1 of which has no code-behind. It runs aok in the IDE but when I installed it on my pc (and also when installed on the production server), and tried to run it this error came up:

```
Parser Error 
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'EMTTrainingDatabase.pageMain'.

Source Error: 


Line 1:  <%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="pageMain.aspx.vb" Inherits="EMTTrainingDatabase.pageMain" %>
Line 2:  
Line 3:  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">


Source File: /EMTTrainingDatabase/pageMain.aspx    Line: 1 


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.3603; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.3082
```

I checked the web site properties in IIS and the correct ASP.net version is specified: 2.0.50727.

I checked the virtual path and it looks correct too: /EMTTrainingDatabase

pageMain source code header looks like:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="pageMain.aspx.vb" Inherits="EMTTrainingDatabase.pageMain" %>
```

Some posters suggest that the bin is in the wrong folder or the bin doesn't contain the rigt contents. I don't have enough knowledge to evaulate this.

Can someone help?

Thank you.

Comment: How did you installed? Could you explain what you did?

Comment: I created a web deployment project for "release", Built the solution and clicked on the resulting .msi file.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to find the answer to my problem:

When I added content to the deployment project, the dll was not in the bin. When I dragged it into the bin, the program worked.

Answer (score 2):

For the benefit of others who might have had the same error, it can also come due to the ASP.NET runtime being unable to locate the /bin folder.

For this, make sure you have marked the virtual directory containing your application as a web application root.

e.g. In godaddy web hosting you should mark *Set Application Root* to the folder/sub-folder containing your application. (Making it a virtual directory is not enough).

Hope it will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the **CodeBehind** attribute with **CodeFile**